# Using Excel VBA to automatically move to cell if value changes

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I have put values in columns from C to F, with G being the calculation from these cells (C to F).

Is there a way to automatically move to cell C in next row when I put the number in cell F at the end?

I have tried using macro plus VBA but it seems there is a problem.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$H$6" Then
        Call Macro1
    End If
End Sub
```

MACRO

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

In H6, I used the SUM of the F cell to trigger it but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are checking only for the cell `H6`. It will only move if you type something in `H6` other cells will have no effect.

So, test for the F column (number 6):

```
if Target.Column = 6 then
     ....
endif
```

Since the acive cell is probably below the one edited (if user pressed enter) or anywhere else (if user just clicked another place), using `ActiveCell` will be a bad thing, use the changed row instead:

```
if Target.Column = 6 then
     call Macro1(Target.row)
end if


Sub Macro1(row as integer)
     Worksheets("TheNameOfTheSheet").Cells(row,3).Select
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will only fire if the user changes the value in cell H6. It doesn't fire if that value is changed due to a calculation (ie because the user changes the value in another cell). This is mentioned in the MSDN documentation for the Worksheet Change event at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx.

Also, I would suggest not using ActiveCell.Offset as you don't know which cell will be active when macro1 is run. If the user types a number in F6 and presses enter then F7 becomes the Activecell, but if the user types a number and presses the right arrow key, it will be cell G6.

Instead of using ActiveCell, you can use Target from the Change event, as we know that is the cell that was updated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$6" Then
        Macro1 LastCell:=Target
    End If
End Sub

Sub Macro1(LastCell As Range)
    LastCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
End Sub
```

If you have more than one row of data and want to repeat the macro for a number of cells in F, you may want to test for a specific Colum (F), and a range of Row numbers, instead of one cell address. There's also no real need to call a separate sub unless you're doing something more complex. You might want to try something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Row < 10 Then
            Target.Offset(1, -3).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

(You'd need to adjust the Row numbers according to your needs).